# Enumerating n-gon rings

Tags: geometry, elementary-number-theory

How many rings can be constructed from a set of regular $n$-gons?

For this purpose a ring is planar arrangement of $m \ge 2$ identical non-overlapping regular $n$-gons joined edge to edge, the whole arrangement having $m$-fold rotational symmetry. The task is to find the values of $m$ for which such a ring can be made.

This problem occurred to me while playing with a child’s toy. It has a nice solution which is not hard to find.

[image]

A ring of 6 nonagons . . . . . . . . . . . . . . Interlinked rings of dodecagons.